# Does changing and reverting back observable within the same action trigger updates?

Tags: javascript, observable, mobx, mobx-react

If observable was changed several times within the same action and as result, the observable value equals the initial value (before the action) - does this trigger mobX observable updates?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this - yes, this triggers mobx observable updates. React components are re-rendered, so the observable is treated as changed.